# How to pass tech review while submitting extension - Varnish error

Tags: magento2

While submitting an extension compatible with Magento 2.x, it failed the Technical review, and the test reports show this error:

**Command:**

Varnish PageCache Test

**Output:**

Cannot update product price.

**Response:**

```
{\"messages\":{\"error\":[{\"code\":500,\"message\":\"Server internal error. See details in report api\\/1143348353039\"}]}}
```

From the above message, if am not wrong, am supposed to check in var/report/1143348353039 file but it's Magento's server, not sure how to get more details about the bug.

Have been on this for some time now, had posted on Magento forums without much avail. This particular error is a result of the command "Varnish PageCache Test".

Inorder to reproduce the error at my end, tried installing and configuring varnish, but I don't see any tools which use such a command which leads me to believe its a user-defined one.

Any inputs on how to debug/solve this, leading to a successful extension submission, will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

**Update:**

Finally got a response for the ticket raised in Magento MarketPlace - They sent the error stack - was pretty straight forward from there. Had missed exception handling at a point :/